# Salvar 2 modelos no mesmo id do firebase

Tags: java, android, mobile

Tenho 2 modelos , o entregador e o veículo , preciso salvar os dados dos dois modelos no mesmo `id` do *database*, fiz da seguinte forma , usei o veículo. `salvarDados();` porém não salvou:

```
private void cadastrarEntregador() {
    autenticacao = ConfiguracaoFirebase.getFirebaseAutenticacao();
    autenticacao.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
        entregador.getEmail(),
        entregador.getSenha()
    ).addOnCompleteListener(
        CadastroEntregadorActivity.this, 
        new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    snack("Conta criada com sucesso");
                    entregador.setId(task.getResult().getUser().getUid());
                    entregador.salvarDados();
                    veiculo.salvarDados();
```

Comment: Poste o código do `salvarDados()`, por favor. Desta forma poderei entender melhor o problema.